# Sharing a regularly updating json data feed between 2 controllers angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an application that reads from one regularly updating public flickr feed (e.g. https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=christmas&tagmode=all&format=json). When you click on an item it goes to a separate view displaying information regarding that particaular item.

These are **my 2 controllers** both loading data from the same service flickrImages

```
imageFeedControllers.controller('ImageListController', ['$scope','flickrImages',
  function ($scope,flickrImages) {
      $scope.imagesData = flickrImages.load({ tags: tag });

  }]);

imageFeedControllers.controller('ImageDetailsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams',        'flickrImages', '$sce', 'descriptionOnlyFilter',
  function ($scope, $routeParams, flickrImages, $sce, descriptionOnlyFilter) {      
      $scope.imagesData = flickrImages.load({ tags: tag }, function (images) {
          var imageId = $routeParams.imageId;
          $scope.imageData = images.items[imageId];

      });
  }]);
```

**my service**

```
imageFeedServices.factory('flickrImages', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    var publicPhotoBaseUrl = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne';

    return imagesData = $resource(publicPhotoBaseUrl, { tagmode: 'all', format: 'json',  jsoncallback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' }, {
        load: { method: 'JSONP'}
    });
```

My problem is that by the time I click on an item in the image list the feed has updated therefore the image details view displays a different image to the one I clicked on. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: You'd need a unique identifier, not just the index in the list, as a parameter

Comment: The issue is that the items in the feed does not have a unique identifier. Or I cant see one anyway

Comment: The link has a unique photo id. You can either cache the item details in your flickrImages service, or use another flickr API to get potentially more info (I'm not familiar with Flickr APIs)

Comment: Adding ",cache:true" after "{method: 'JSONP'" in my factory seems to resolve the issue

Comment: But then it would not refresh the list, unless you invalidate the cache

Comment: I am quite new to caching using angularjs do you know of any better ways to do this?

Comment: Cache can work, you just need to somehow force the cache to get updated. Red more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache